# How to determine shape of outermost boundary of object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, contour

I'm trying to classify images into two categories using only opencv. Category1 contents images of object type whose outer boundaries are of U shape and category2 contents images of object type whose outer boundaries are of L shape. Images are of as below

as you can see above images both category object outter boundary are of shape U and L as marked in red color as shown below

In order to achieve how can I track outer perimeter of object and check its shape if it's of type L or U .

I tried finding the contours of image and perimeter as shown in below code,

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
img = cv.imread('image.jpg',0)
ret, thresh = cv.threshold(img,127,255,0)
contours, hierarchy = cv.findContours(thresh, 1, 2)

cnt = contours[0]
area = cv.contourArea()  # Area of first contour
perimeter = cv.arcLength(cnt, True)  # Perimeter of first contour
```

I'm not sure how to proceed further to parse outer boundary from many contour perimeters and check the shape of it.

Any suggestions or other methods on how to solve this will be highly appreciated

Comment: You're going to have all sorts of problems as your `L` image could easily be a `U` image as well depending on how you segment out the image information. Basically if there are no unique quailities that separate the 2 types of image I cant see how you can do this.

Comment: Your classification as U or L does not seem appropriate. In particular, both kinds have a left and an upper straight edge. Do you want to rely on symmetry/asymmetry, or on the presence/absence of a single straight edge on the right ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust thanks for reply, yes your correct both have similar left and upper straight edge. I think relying on symmetry/asymmetry along with presence / absence of single straight edge will help to segregate. can you guide me in the right path inorder to implement this for the above images?how can i find symmetry in the image and presence of edge on right?

Comment: What do you think ?

Comment: I tried looking for source showing how to quantify assymetry in image but I couldn't find any working example and to find longer straight edge I think I can find out largest area of rectangle contour,I'm not sure if this work, whats ur thoughts?